Dart: Go back to previous screen after dialog, menu closes and fire off a REST POST
I have a submenu that pops up from the bottom of the screen. The 3rd menu item is "Deactivate this Quest" deactivateThisQuest.tr(), when the user taps it, it calls the onsubmit() function that has a popup dialog with "Cancel" and "OK", tapping "Cancel" closes the dialog and closes the menu as expected, tapping "OK" sends a REST POST back to the server.
What I am trying to do is when the user clicks "OK" on the popup dialog I want it to got back to the previous screen. But in order to do this it needs to close the dialog box, then close the popup menu that we called earlier and THEN go back to the previous screen.
If I put 3 "Navigator.pop(context);" in a row like shown below, it goes to the previous screen as expected but doesn't fire the API POST. If I put 2 "Navigator.pop(context);" in a row, then the dialog and menu closes and the API fires. If I put a "Navigator.pop(context);" after the onRefresh(); function the dialog and menu close, the API fires but STILL doesn't go back to the previous screen.
Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?
class QuestMenu extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const QuestMenu(
      {super.key,
      required this.questId,
      required this.questName,
      required this.privateLink,
      required this.onRefresh,
      this.token,
      required this.isJoined,
      required this.isDeactivated});

  final int questId;
  final String questName;
  final String privateLink;
  final String? token;
  final VoidCallback onRefresh;
  final bool isJoined;
  final bool isDeactivated;

  void show(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => QuestMenu(
          questId: questId,
          questName: questName,
          privateLink: privateLink,
          token: token,
          onRefresh: onRefresh,
          isJoined: isJoined,
          isDeactivated: isDeactivated),
      useRootNavigator: true,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
          topRight: Radius.circular(16),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    final onSubmit = useCallback(
      () async {
        // Show confirmation dialog
        await showDialog<bool>(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 20,
                vertical: 24,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'deactivateQuest'.tr(),
                style: popupTitle.copyWith(color: Palette.titleColor),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              content: Text(
                'sureDeactivate'.tr(),
                style: basicText.copyWith(color: Palette.generalText),
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              ),
              actions: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: OutlineButton(
                        label: 'Cancel',
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context); // Close dialog
                          Navigator.pop(context); // Close menu
                        },
                        //child: Text('Cancel'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    gapW8, // Adjust spacing between buttons
                    Expanded(
                      child: PrimaryButton(
                        label: 'OK',
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Navigator.pop(context); // Close dialog
                          Navigator.pop(context); // Close menu
                          Navigator.pop(context); // Go back to previous screen
                          await ref
                              .read(deactivateQuestNotifierProvider.notifier)
                              .deactivateQuest(questId, token: token);
                          onRefresh();
                          //Navigator.pop(context); // Go back to previous screen
                        },
                        //child: Text('Confirm'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
      [],
    );

    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(pdMdHorizontal),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            _MenuTile(
              label: 'clickView'.tr(),
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.routeFilled),
              showChevron: true,
              onTap: () {
                launchUrl(url);
              },
            ),
            gapH16,
            _MenuTile(
              label: 'shareWithFriend'.tr(),
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.share),
              showChevron: true,
              onTap: () => Share.share(privateLink),
            ),
            gapH16,
            if (isJoined && !isDeactivated)
              _MenuTile(
                label: 'deactivateThisQuest'.tr(),
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.flasher),
                showChevron: true,
                onTap: onSubmit,
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MenuTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MenuTile({
    required this.icon,
    required this.label,
    this.onTap,
    this.showChevron = false,
  });

  final SvgPicture icon;
  final String label;
  final bool showChevron;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          icon,
          gapW10,
          Text(label, style: buttonText.copyWith(color: Palette.activeGreen)),
          if (showChevron) const Spacer(),
          if (showChevron) SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.chevronNext),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Modify onPressed:
onPressed: () async {
  Navigator.pop(context); // Close dialog
  Navigator.pop(context); // Close menu
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)); // Delay for smooth transition (optional)
  Navigator.pop(context); // Go back to previous screen
  await ref
      .read(deactivateQuestNotifierProvider.notifier)
      .deactivateQuest(questId, token: token);
  onRefresh();
},

"Future.delayed" with a short duration after closing the menu to allows the smooth transition before going back to the previous screen
